# How to store and use dynamic values from range sliders?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got two range sliders (ion range sliders) which dynamically show the hours and minutes that the user has scrolled to select. How do I store these values using local storage and then manipulate them to put them in a different page.

Scenario example: User selects 12 hours and 22 minutes. On refresh of this page, the value the user put remains and when the user goes to another page, these values are added in a new row.

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQLyza

I tried using the below to store the variable minutes but it did not work:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'Test', minutes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but adding the three line below to your code works - does that help. Additional info - [MDN localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
var updateValuesMinutes = function(){
  $to.prop("value", to);
  localStorage.setItem( 'Test', to); // add line 1 of 3
  let minuteCheck = localStorage.getItem("Test"); // add line 2 of 3
  console.log(minuteCheck); // add line 3 of 3
};
```

Here's those lines added to [your pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQPQyd?editors=1111) and the minute value shows correctly in the console.

Updated to set initial values for minutes in text display ([updated PEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQPQyd?editors=1111)) - still need to reset the slider itself:

Here's the code added to the bottom (could be cleaner but just quick and dirty didn't check into which to use between from and $to.prop() - or maybe both needed) - based on the syntax of the function with parenthesis and ending with a semi-colon makes it execute immediately - that what the doc explains.:

```
(function () { 
  from = 0; // initial set to 0
  $to.prop("value", 0); // initial set to zero
  if (localStorage.getItem("Test"))  { // does the localStoreage exist
    $to.prop("value", localStorage.getItem("Test")); // yes set text
    from = $to.prop; // yes set text
}
})();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!

I am creating a clock web app where the user creates and sets and alarm. In my codepen its part of the screen where the user sets the hours and minutes. I want to be able to store that data so that it gets added in another screen where there is a list of alarms where the user can choose; similar to how the ios clock works.

I tried out your codepen edits but the data gets reset on refresh. I need it to persist on this screen and also be able to take these local stored values and insert them in an element on another page.

hope that's clear

Comment: Those are separate items and you'll need to update your code to initialize the clock settings on startup from the saved values. Hopefully you did notice that you can still enter `localStorage.getItem("Test");` in the console and see the value at it was prior to hitting refresh - an immediately executed function could be a good place to start (don't forget the 1 time before any storage save) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: Sorry, my js is still quite new. I see that it is being outputted to console.log and I've mirrored it so that both hours and minutes are logged. However how do I go about inserting it in the text areas above the slider so that it remains after refresh? Was not able to understand the IIFE link

Comment: Yep - good start and some areas to investigate are your function calling with parameters, understand scope and how you are polluting the global scope. I make a little update to my fork of your pen - will put it in the answer above since easier...

Comment: cheers, thanks this is really helpful! I can see how it is a bit messy with how I write my scripts so I'll check into what you said about the global scope.

For the sliders, why do they reset to the start position but the values they point to persist? Do I have to write the same function but in reverse to target the position of the slider?

Comment: Hey going back on this, I'm struggling to keep the slider position where it is on refresh. Is this something I need to store in local storage? How do I store the position?